# User defined function for Toast

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toast

I am new in android development using java and now am working or Toast .
I need help that we make a user defined function which initiate our toast and where ever we want toast we just pass values like activity context message and duration and that function show the toast as required ?

can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method from anywhere:

```
public void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show()
}
```

Make BaseActivity or BaseFragment and put this method there
and extends all activity by `BaseActivity` or fragments by `BaseFragment`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that one way is define a class as:

```
public class Shared {
    private static Shared object = null;
    private Shared() {}
    public static Shared getInstance() {
        if (object == null) {  
          synchronized(Shared.class) {
            object = new Shared();
          }
        }
        return object;
    }

    public void showToast(Context context, String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show()
    }

}
```

**Call showToast method from anywhere like:**

```
Shared.getInstance().showToast(ActivityA.this,"Hello");
```

**Second way is to define a method in your BaseActivity or BaseFragment like this:**

```
public void showToast(Context context, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, duration).show()
}
```

and call it from `Activity` or `fragment` like this `showToast(ActivityA.this,"Hello");`

Comment: really this method make my work perfect..Thanks hope need ur help in future

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText()` takes three arguments - The context, the message to be displayed, and the time. If you want a short toast, then use the below code.

```
public void showToast(Context context, String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Else, use the below one for a long toast.

```
public void showToast(Context context, String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You can have only two durations that is default in android. You can't set a custom toast time.

Comment: Thanks Man Its really helpful to understandn